# Titanium TCP/IP socket read buffered data

Tags: tcp, titanium, buffer

I am reading a tcp-ip socket response (JSON) from the server. The issue is that sometimes if the data that is received from the server is very large it comes in batches of 2 or 3 with a random break in the JSON. Is there a way to detect how many batches are being sent from the server or is there a mechanism to tackle this at the client end? Below is the titanium code for TCP/IP:

```
var socket = Ti.Network.Socket.createTCP({
host: '127.0.0.1', 
port: 5000,
connected: function (e) {
    Ti.API.info('Socket opened!');
    Ti.Stream.pump(socket, readCallback, 2048, true);
},
    error: function (e) {
    Ti.API.info('Error (' + e.errorCode + '): ' + JSON.stringify(e));
},
});

socket.connect();

function writeCallback(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Successfully wrote to socket.'+JSON.stringify(e));
}

function readCallback(e) {
Ti.API.info('e ' + JSON.stringify(e));
if (e.bytesProcessed == -1)
{
    // Error / EOF on socket. Do any cleanup here.
    Ti.API.info('DONE');
}
try {
    if(e.buffer) {
        var received = e.buffer.toString();
        Ti.API.info('Received: ' + received);

    } else {
        Ti.API.error('Error: read callback called with no buffer!');
        socket.close();
    }
} catch (ex) {
    Ti.API.error('Catch ' + ex);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP is a streaming interface and there is no guarantee from the client side how much data will be received when a read is attempted from the socket.

You would have to implement some sort of protocol between the server and the client.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP Protocol is not designed like that, you cannot know how much data you will receive, it's in darkness lol

There are two ways to solve this problem, as I know.

**The first One is EOF, you will add something as a prefix at the end of the packet, and it's a unique string like [%~Done~%]**

so? you will receive everything and search in it about this string, did you find it? let's go to processing.

but I saw it as wasting of time, memory, and very primitive

**the second one is Prefix Packet header**, and it's the best for me, an example in .NET can be located here: [Thanks to Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html)